# Convert Json to XML String with namespace?

Tags: c#, xml, json, json.net

I have a json string like this

```
"{
  "RSS": {
    "Channel": {
      "item": [
        {
          "title": "Overlay HD/CC",
          "guid": "1",
          "description": "This example shows tooltip overlays for captions and quality.",
          "jwplayer:image": "http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/3XnJSIm4-640.jpg",
          "jwplayer:source": [
            {
              "@file": "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-DZ7jSYgM.mp4",
              "@label": "720p"
            },
            {
              "@file": "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-kNspJqnJ.mp4",
              "@label": "360p"
            },
            {
              "@file": "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-injeKYZS.mp4",
              "@label": "180p"
            }
          ],
          "jwplayer:track": [
            {
              "@file": "http://content.jwplatform.com/captions/2UEDrDhv.txt",
              "@label": "English"
            },
            {
              "@file": "http://content.jwplatform.com/captions/6aaGiPcs.txt",
              "@label": "Japanese"
            },
            {
              "@file": "http://content.jwplatform.com/captions/2nxzdRca.txt",
              "@label": "Russian"
            },
            {
              "@file": "http://content.jwplatform.com/captions/BMjSl0KC.txt",
              "@label": "Spanish"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "@xmlns:jwplayer": "http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference#feeds",
    "@version": "2.0"
  }
}"
```

I tried using json.net to convert it to xmlDocument:

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
using (var xmlTextWriter = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter))
{
    xmlDoc.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter); // Exception: Cannot use a prefix with an empty namespace.
    xmlTextWriter.Flush();
    return stringWriter.GetStringBuilder().ToString();
}
```

But when i try to access OuterXml property, it throw exception "Cannot use a prefix with an empty namespace."

Is there anyway to fix that exception or another method to convert json to xml string?
the xml string have namespace as below

```
<jwplayer:image>http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/3XnJSIm4-640.jpg</jwplayer:image>
```

Comment: return xmlDoc.OuterXml

Comment: Thanks for this question - it took several hours of googling to work out how to get Json.net to respect XML namespaces. I took a guess that `@xmlns : "url"` would set the default namespace, and indeed it does. This feature is pretty poorly documented.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why your code throws exception because it must've been a valid XML since the XML loaded successfully to `XmlDocument` object.

Another way I can think to get formatted XML string is by using loading the unformatted XML string from `XmlDocument.OuterXml` to `XDocument` then convert it to formatted XML string :

```
XmlDocument xmlDoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXmlNode(json);
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlDoc.OuterXml);
return xDoc.ToString();
```

Not an efficient one, but this approach is simple and worked.

Comment: Thanks you so much. I found myself use xmlDoc.OuterXml solve the problem already.

Comment: More problem, it show <image>hxxp://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/3XnJSIm4-640.jpg</image> but my expected is <jwplayer:image>hxxp://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/3XnJSIm4-640.jpg</jwplayer:image>

Answer (score 0):

Put the schema information just after the main element here is RSS. After that, it works with Newtosoft.

```
{
  "RSS": {
    "@xmlns:jwplayer": "http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference#feeds",
    "@version": "2.0",
    "Channel": {
      "item": [
        {
          "title": "Overlay HD/CC",
          "guid": "1",
          "description": "This example shows tooltip overlays for captions and quality.",
          "jwplayer:image": "http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/3XnJSIm4-640.jpg",
          "jwplayer:source": [
            {
              "@file": "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-DZ7jSYgM.mp4",
              "@label": "720p"
            },
            {
              "@file": "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-kNspJqnJ.mp4",
              "@label": "360p"
            },
            {
              "@file": "http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-injeKYZS.mp4",
              "@label": "180p"
            }
          ],
          "jwplayer:track": [
            {
              "@file": "http://content.jwplatform.com/captions/2UEDrDhv.txt",
              "@label": "English"
            },
            {
              "@file": "http://content.jwplatform.com/captions/6aaGiPcs.txt",
              "@label": "Japanese"
            },
            {
              "@file": "http://content.jwplatform.com/captions/2nxzdRca.txt",
              "@label": "Russian"
            },
            {
              "@file": "http://content.jwplatform.com/captions/BMjSl0KC.txt",
              "@label": "Spanish"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

And result is

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<RSS xmlns:jwplayer="http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1403635-media-format-reference#feeds" version="2.0">
  <Channel>
    <item>
      <title>Overlay HD/CC</title>
      <guid>1</guid>
      <description>This example shows tooltip overlays for captions and quality.</description>
      <jwplayer:image>http://content.jwplatform.com/thumbs/3XnJSIm4-640.jpg</jwplayer:image>
      <jwplayer:source file="http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-DZ7jSYgM.mp4" label="720p" />
      <jwplayer:source file="http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-kNspJqnJ.mp4" label="360p" />
      <jwplayer:source file="http://content.jwplatform.com/videos/3XnJSIm4-injeKYZS.mp4" label="180p" />
      <jwplayer:track file="http://content.jwplatform.com/captions/2UEDrDhv.txt" label="English" />
      <jwplayer:track file="http://content.jwplatform.com/captions/6aaGiPcs.txt" label="Japanese" />
      <jwplayer:track file="http://content.jwplatform.com/captions/2nxzdRca.txt" label="Russian" />
      <jwplayer:track file="http://content.jwplatform.com/captions/BMjSl0KC.txt" label="Spanish" />
    </item>
  </Channel>
</RSS>
```